# how do I put a line break among multiple tikzpictures?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

If I do this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3,>=latex, font=\sffamily]
\draw [->](0,0) -- (0,1) node[at end, above left, rotate=90] {engine output};
\draw [->](0,0) -- (1,0) node[at end, below left] {pedal input};
\draw [-](0,0) -- (0.8,0.8);
\draw [dashed, ->](0.8,0.8) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3,>=latex, font=\sffamily]
\draw [->](0,0) -- (0,1) node[at end, above left, rotate=90] {engine output};
\draw [->](0,0) -- (1,0) node[at end, below left] {pedal input};
\draw [-](0,0) -- (0.8,0.8);
\draw [dashed, ->](0.8,0.8) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\newline
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3,>=latex, font=\sffamily]
\draw [->](0,0) -- (0,1) node[at end, above left, rotate=90] {engine output};
\draw [->](0,0) -- (1,0) node[at end, below left] {pedal input};
\draw [-](0,0) -- (0.8,0.8);
\draw [dashed, ->](0.8,0.8) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3,>=latex, font=\sffamily]
\draw [->](0,0) -- (0,1) node[at end, above left, rotate=90] {engine output};
\draw [->](0,0) -- (1,0) node[at end, below left] {pedal input};
\draw [-](0,0) -- (0.8,0.8);
\draw [dashed, ->](0.8,0.8) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I get this, rather than a 2x2 grid of graphs:

[image]

How do I modify it so I get a 2x2 grid of graphs?

Comment: Use another class e.g. `article`.

Comment: is there another way? I don't want the full page size, I just want it to include the drawing, so that when I convert to PDF and then to PNG it doesn't have unnecessary whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use just one `tikzpicture`, and move each part around with a `scope` environment and some `shift`s.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3,>=latex, font=\sffamily]
\draw [->](0,0) -- (0,1) node[at end, above left, rotate=90] {engine output};
\draw [->](0,0) -- (1,0) node[at end, below left] {pedal input};
\draw [-](0,0) -- (0.8,0.8);
\draw [dashed, ->](0.8,0.8) -- (1,1);

\begin{scope}[xshift=1.3cm]
\draw [->](0,0) -- (0,1) node[at end, above left, rotate=90] {engine output};
\draw [->](0,0) -- (1,0) node[at end, below left] {pedal input};
\draw [-](0,0) -- (0.8,0.8);
\draw [dashed, ->](0.8,0.8) -- (1,1);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[yshift=-1.3cm]
\draw [->](0,0) -- (0,1) node[at end, above left, rotate=90] {engine output};
\draw [->](0,0) -- (1,0) node[at end, below left] {pedal input};
\draw [-](0,0) -- (0.8,0.8);
\draw [dashed, ->](0.8,0.8) -- (1,1);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[shift={(1.3cm,-1.3cm)}]
\draw [->](0,0) -- (0,1) node[at end, above left, rotate=90] {engine output};
\draw [->](0,0) -- (1,0) node[at end, below left] {pedal input};
\draw [-](0,0) -- (0.8,0.8);
\draw [dashed, ->](0.8,0.8) -- (1,1);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following. Note that this relies on an experimental package and so cannot be guaranteed as future-proof. To avoid the experimental package, you could use the underlying stuff provided by the LaTeX 3 kernel development since the equivalent programming functions are not marked as experimental - only the user-level interface which I use here.

## *Caveat emptor ...*

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,xcoffins}
\begin{document}
\NewCoffin\myCoffin
\SetHorizontalCoffin\myCoffin{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3,>=latex, font=\sffamily]
    \draw [->](0,0) -- (0,1) node[at end, above left, rotate=90] {engine output};
    \draw [->](0,0) -- (1,0) node[at end, below left] {pedal input};
    \draw [-](0,0) -- (0.8,0.8);
    \draw [dashed, ->](0.8,0.8) -- (1,1);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3,>=latex, font=\sffamily]
    \draw [->](0,0) -- (0,1) node[at end, above left, rotate=90] {engine output};
    \draw [->](0,0) -- (1,0) node[at end, below left] {pedal input};
    \draw [-](0,0) -- (0.8,0.8);
    \draw [dashed, ->](0.8,0.8) -- (1,1);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}%
\NewCoffin\mySpareCoffin
\SetHorizontalCoffin\mySpareCoffin{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3,>=latex, font=\sffamily]
    \draw [->](0,0) -- (0,1) node[at end, above left, rotate=90] {engine output};
    \draw [->](0,0) -- (1,0) node[at end, below left] {pedal input};
    \draw [-](0,0) -- (0.8,0.8);
    \draw [dashed, ->](0.8,0.8) -- (1,1);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3,>=latex, font=\sffamily]
    \draw [->](0,0) -- (0,1) node[at end, above left, rotate=90] {engine output};
    \draw [->](0,0) -- (1,0) node[at end, below left] {pedal input};
    \draw [-](0,0) -- (0.8,0.8);
    \draw [dashed, ->](0.8,0.8) -- (1,1);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}%
\JoinCoffins\myCoffin [b,l] \mySpareCoffin [t,l]
\TypesetCoffin\myCoffin
\end{document}
```

[image: 2x2]

Obviously, this must also be possible with lower level TeX, but coffins are a lot easier!

Answer (score 2):

Page 10 of the manual, use the `varwidth` option.

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3,>=latex, font=\sffamily]
\draw [->](0,0) -- (0,1) node[at end, above left, rotate=90] {engine output};
\draw [->](0,0) -- (1,0) node[at end, below left] {pedal input};
\draw [-](0,0) -- (0.8,0.8);
\draw [dashed, ->](0.8,0.8) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3,>=latex, font=\sffamily]
\draw [->](0,0) -- (0,1) node[at end, above left, rotate=90] {engine output};
\draw [->](0,0) -- (1,0) node[at end, below left] {pedal input};
\draw [-](0,0) -- (0.8,0.8);
\draw [dashed, ->](0.8,0.8) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3,>=latex, font=\sffamily]
\draw [->](0,0) -- (0,1) node[at end, above left, rotate=90] {engine output};
\draw [->](0,0) -- (1,0) node[at end, below left] {pedal input};
\draw [-](0,0) -- (0.8,0.8);
\draw [dashed, ->](0.8,0.8) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3,>=latex, font=\sffamily]
\draw [->](0,0) -- (0,1) node[at end, above left, rotate=90] {engine output};
\draw [->](0,0) -- (1,0) node[at end, below left] {pedal input};
\draw [-](0,0) -- (0.8,0.8);
\draw [dashed, ->](0.8,0.8) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I didn't fix the missing `%` in the second row, as it may be an unwanted `%` in the first row. Take your pick.